# Die Wörter „für“ und „vor“

Tags: etymology, preposition

Bei Luther habe ich an einigen Stellen ein „für“ gefunden, wo ich ein „vor“ erwartet hätte. Wie ist die Herkunft dieser beiden Wörter, und wie hängen sie zusammen?

[Ein Beispiel:](https://books.google.de/books?id=mv1BAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT648&dq=%22f%C3%BCr%20den%20leuten%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dIFIVZ2jDMGsswGHwIDoCw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22f%C3%BCr%20den%20leuten%22&f=false)

> Das soll ihr lernen/das es nit allein für Gott war ist/sonder auch für den Leuten/denn die art haben alle die menschen/das sie den hoffertigen feind sind.

Viele weitere Beispiele (auch bessere) findet man hier: [hier](https://books.google.de/books?id=fPQ9AAAAcAAJ&pg=RA6-PA382&dq=%22f%C3%BCr%20den%20leuten%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dIFIVZ2jDMGsswGHwIDoCw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22f%C3%BCr%20den%20leuten%22&f=false)

Comment: Hülfe, da sollten Links sein, aber sie funktionieren (für mich?) nicht. Kann jemand helfen?

Comment: Füge einfach die URL ein. Jemand anders kann es dann editieren, damit der Link funktioniert.

Comment: Ah, URL encoding, could have thought of that. Tack så mycket!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Die beiden Wörter *für* und *vor* haben tatsächlich einen gemeinsamen Ursprung und sind erst allmählich divergiert. Ähnliches gilt für die englischen Wörter *for* und *[be]fore*. Im Niederländischen gibt es dagegen nur ein Wort mit beiden Bedeutungen: *voor*.

Das Luther-Beispiel (und insbesondere die Reaktion von raznagul darauf) zeigt, dass die Übergänge zwischen *für* und *vor* auch heute noch fließend sind. Heute sagt man zwar, etwas ist wahr *vor* Gott bzw. *vor* den Leuten. *Für* wäre hier aber mindestens genauso logisch: etwas ist wahr *für* Gott oder *für* die Leute.

Um die Zeit Luthers herum wurde den vielen regionalen Dialekten mit ihren jeweiligen Schreibtraditionen eine einheitliche "hochdeutsche" Sprache und Schrift zur Seite gestellt, die oft feinsinnige Unterscheidungen traf, wo die meisten Dialekte das bereits nicht mehr oder noch nicht taten. Dadurch kam es zwangsläufig zunächst zu gewissen Unsicherheiten. Schließlich war damals niemand mit Hochdeutsch aufgewachsen, und auch alle älteren Bücher waren nicht in Hochdeutsch geschrieben.

In diesem Fall erkennen wir an der Formulierung "für *den* Leuten", dass Luther tatsächlich die Bedeutung meinte, die wir heute immer als *vor* schreiben. Für uns ist heute klar, dass *für* + Dativ gar nicht geht, aber solche Regeln brauchten erst eine Weile, um zu entstehen, sich durchzusetzen und von allen verinnerlicht zu werden.

PS: Soweit basierte meine Antwort auf Allgemeinwissen statt auf speziellen Kenntnissen. Inzwischen habe ich aber eine interessante Quelle ergooglet:

> Ein Grundzug der wortgeschichtlichen Entwicklung, der sich beim Übergang zum Nhd. spürbar verstärkt, ist die genauere Abgrenzung sich berührender oder überlappender Anwendungsbereiche sinn- und funktionsverwandter Wörter. Nicht selten kommt es dabei nach einer Zeit unsicheren Sprachgebrauchs zu einer Neugliederung des betreffenden Feldes, wo z.B. *für, als, manch, mögen, tun* gegenüber den expansiven *vor, wie, viel, können, machen* einen speziellen Operationsraum zugewiesen erhalten [...].
> Besonders bei den Kleinwörtern nehmen die frnhd. Grammatiker auf die Neuregelung Einfluss, suchen sie zumindest klar zu fixieren, z.B. J. Bödiker [...] 1690 [...]:
>
> "Bisher ist ein alter Irrtuhm vorgangen mit dem *Für* und *Vor* ... Weil nemlich *Vor* bedeutet die Gegenwart, Zeit, Vorzug u.s.w.; so kan *Für* das nicht bedeuten ... Weil nun *vor* den Dativum hat in allen seinen Bedeutungen (außgenommen ad locum); so kan *für* keinen Dativum haben ... *für* und *vor* war damals (d.h. zur Zeit Luthers) nicht unterschieden; nunmehr aber ist der Unterschied gemercket."

Quelle: [Johannes Erben 1970](https://books.google.de/books?id=nizdi_i-Be8C&pg=PA437&lpg=PA437)

(Anmerkung: Bei all den von Erben aufgezählten "Kleinwörtern" fällt auf, dass sie im Niederländischen anders verwendet werden. Das Niederländische hat sich ja um diese Zeit herum vom Deutschen abgespalten und hat diese Entwicklungen offenbar so nicht mitgemacht - dafür aber sicher andere.)

PPS: Anderswo zitiert [Susan Schlothauer](http://www.linguistics.fi/julkaisut/SKY2011/Schlotthauer_netti.pdf) aus Adelung 1811 (Grammatisch-kritisches Wörterbuch der hochdeutschen Mundart, mit beständiger Vergleichung der übrigen Mundarten, besonders aber der Oberdeutschen) so:

> "„(...) es ist gewiß, daß man vor Luthers Zeiten keinen Schriftsteller aufweisen kann, der beyde Vorwörter [*für* und *vor*] beständig und mit Bewußtseyn unterschieden hätte".

Comment: Danke, die Antwort ist definitiv die Bessere. +1 von mir.

Comment: Interessanter Hinweis auf das Niederländische.

Comment: Hallo Hans, vielen Dank für die Antwort. Ein wenig hatte ich gehofft, jemand, der sich damit auskennt, würde eine etwas tiefer gehende Beschreibung dessen, was da vorgegangen ist, aus dem Ärmel schütteln, die mir die Mühe erspart, den langen Eintrag im Grimmschen Wörterbuch zu lesen, den ich ohne Vorkenntnisse ohnehin nur halb verstehen werde, aber das kann man natürlich nicht erwarten.

Answer (score 2):

An dieser Stelle ist halte ich *für* für richtig.

Ich versuche mich mal an einer *Übersetzung*:

> Ihr sollt lernen, dass es nicht allein für Gott wahr ist, sondern auch *für* die Leute; denn es ist die Art aller Menschen, dass sie den Anmaßenden Feind sind.

Man darf mich gerne korrigieren.

Comment: @Em1: Thanks for the edit. But im quite sure that "anmanßenden" should be written with an capital A. "Anmaßenden" doesn't desciribe Feind but references the object thats spoken about. You could also rephrase the sentance to ", dass sie der Feind der Anmaßenden sind."

Comment: Das zeigt, dass die Wörter näher beieinander liegen als einem heute bewusst ist, denn hier ist wohl beides denkbar. Mein Beispiel war leider nicht das deutlichste.

Comment: @raznagul Das erklärt, warum mir der Teil des Satzes sowieso Spanisch vorkam. Jetzt versteh ich es aber auch :)